# Create HTTP request between localhost servers with Sails and Express

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, sails.js

Currently I want to communicate 2 applications, one of them with Sailsjs (port 1337) and the other with Express (port 3000). For testing purposes I'm working on localhost.

App with Sails recieves an URL and, in some cases, must redirect to the other program, but this redirection does not work.

From Express doc, I should be able to use `res.redirect` to set the redirection. I keep running 2 servers and send info with Postman as follows:

[image]

This is the code of the Sails.js application, a policy (middleware) that should redirect

```
module.exports = function notExpiredTokens(req,res,next){

    console.log('Pasa por notExpiredTokens');  //-> Checks it is called

    res.redirect(301, 'localhost:3000');
    res.end();                            //--> Redirection is ignored
                                          // Also tried with send(), but does not work.


    next();
}
```

Of course sending data with Postman to both `localhost:1337/...` and `localhost:3000/...` works fine.

Am I doing something wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://localhost:3000');
```

Add protocol before localhost

Comment: Wow! That was the key! Thanks!